# How do I place a draggable text object among text in a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

What I'm after is the type of text wrapper/token that Gmail uses at least in its address input fields. The objects are presented as boxes that are draggable, have a header and carry at least the email address as content (although the content itself is not presented to the user). Something like the Stackoverflow tags field has if you're unfamiliar with Gmail.

Actually Gmail or stackoverflow aren't perfect examples since I'm looking to inject this kind of wrapped content into text fields, so that they can be dragged among text but specifically in such a way that their own content is safe from modification. The reason is that in our company non IT oriented personnel routinely edit large amounts of text that has plenty of embedded code which obviously still has to work perfectly even after multiple edits.

I'd of course prefer light client side techniques like js but any and all comments are welcome. Thanks :)

Comment: http://skfox.com/jqExamples/insertAtCaret.html but wrapped in a box and safe from harm :)

Comment: <input>, <textarea> or <div> ? you can only do a real box in a  contentEditable div, not a form input.

Comment: I'm after any technique that allows the user to simultaneously manage draggable objects among editable text. So far the contentEditable does sound like half of the solution, I'll have to try how this works out combined with jQuery draggables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI provides dragging and sorting functionality which you can embed in any DOM elements.